# Send post request to restcontroller with url to rest repositories

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I've 2 entities A and B, where A holds an attribute "b" of class B (a one to one association between A and B)

I want to make a rest call to save an instance of A entity, and passing b param as a url which gives something like that in json:

```
{
    "id": "5",
    "b": "/restapi/B/2"
}
```

/b/2 refers to a findById rest resource of B Repository.

When i execute this targetting rest resource save() of A Repository (usually POST request to url /restapi/A), it works just fine, spring looks for the B entity (2 in this example) by calling the rest resource of B Repository.

I want to perform the same behavior using my own rest controller, by defining a @PostMapping function inside a @RestController component.

Is it possible ?

PS: I already tested sending the above JSON with postman, and the rest api interpreet the "/restapi/B/" as String and tries to deserialize B using a string which abviously fails.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to do that.

Comment: For sure it must be possible since this behavior does exists in the exposed rest repositories but i don't want to use exposed rest repositories for security reasons, i want to use my own RestController to controll the insertion of A , and my question is how to achieve it :/

Comment: What about using ID instead of URL? Then you would be able to achieve the same by setting up foreign key relationship (@OneToOne) in the entity

Comment: This would never perform the behavior that i'm looking for (i'll have to fetch B entity by my self) ... and even if i would do so, in my domain modal, A entity holds a reference to B, not the id of the foreign key (for well domain modal representation), and for the rest routine, i'm using RequestBody on A entity, no way to pass the id as a field param :/ ... i ended up by creating another Entity A' which holds all Simple attributes of A plus an id integer supposed to reference B attribute, and this A' would then be the RequestBody of the routine, however this is just a workarround... :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can autowire that repository in your restcontroller and just use it from there. You might need a Transactional annotation.

Also I would suggest to take a look at the project Spring-Data-Rest. This provides you already with what you are trying to build. It is an implementation of the HATEOAS principle.

Comment: I know that i can autowire B Repository to make a findById in my @PostMapping routine to check for B before saving... what i meant is, is it possible to somehow use a certain annotation to make that automaticlly done like it's done with respository rest resource ? ... i read the whole documentation of spring-data-rest and i know it's possible throw RepositoryRestResource but i want to avoid exposing the repository and prefer to implement it for some reasons...

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RepositoryRestController` in your controller class instead of `@RestController`